# Go: Getting unexpected error

Tags: mysql, go

In my controller package, I have a AppContext struct that looks like this:

```
type AppContext struct {
      db *sql.DB
}

func (c *AppContext) getDB() *sql.DB {
      return c.db
}
```

Then I have the following codes in my main package:

```
func main {

db, err := sql.Open("mysql",
        //other info)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
                return 
    }
        err = db.Ping() 
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
                return
        }
    defer db.Close()
        appC := controller.AppContext{db}

}
```

When building it, I get this unexpected error:

```
implicit assignment of unexported field 'db' in controller.AppContext literal
```

I tried looking that error up, but could not find much information on it. Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: You can't initialize an unexported (`db`) field in a structure from another package. Either export it (e.g. `DB`) or make a `New…` function within your `controller` package that takes it as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, `db` is not exported, so inaccessible from other packages.

In Go, initialization of structures is usually done with a function called `NewMyStructure`, so for example:

`func NewAppContext(db *sql.DB) AppContext {
    return AppContext{db: db}
}`

and then in your main:

`appC := controller.NewAppContext(db)`